# Как присвоить переменную типа Camera через метод Start()

Tags: c#, unity3d

В скрипте есть переменная :
`public Camera PlayerCam;`
Через метод `public void Start() { ... }` хочу присвоить этой переменной главную камеру персонажа. Пробывал с помощью

```
PlayerCam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.GetChild(0);
```

Но появляется ошибка, что переменная типа GameObject не может быть занесена в переменную типа Camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы взять главную камеру можете воспользоваться

```
PlayerCam = Camera.main;
```

И как писали выше, вы присваивали не тот тип данных камере.  Если уж вы и находите объект камеры на сцене то берите с неё компонент камеры и присваивайте куда хотите.

```
PlayerCam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите документацию по [GetChild()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) - этот метод возвращает тип `Transform`, а вы пытаетесь сохранить его в переменную типа `Camera`. Если вы хотите получить какой-либо скрипт, прикрепленный, к искомому вами GameObject, то воспользуйтесь методом [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), указав в качестве параметра T - Camera.

Стоит заметить, что код, который вы привели в вопросе крайне не оптимальный и использовать его не стоит. Лучше всего прокидывать ссылки на компоненты и объекты в Inspector.

Comment: В будущем собираюсь сделать игру сетевой. Насколько я знаю, нельзя будет просто взять и перетянуть это все в инспекторе.